# Sorting an array using a boolean array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, pseudocode

Array `A` is an array of `Integer`s, each value can appear only once.

Array `B` is an array of `Boolean`s.

```
B[k] is True  when A[k] > A[k+1]

B[k] is False when A[k] < A[k+1]
```

Is it possible to write a *sort Algorithm* for that uses the `bool` array with the complexity of less than `Tetta(n*logn)`?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's **not possible**. Let's prove it by *contradiction*

**Fact:** In general case, having `A` array of *arbitrary* integers (*arbitrary* in order to make *radix sort* impossible) we can't sort it faster than `O(N * log(N))`.

Suppose we have an algortihm better than `O(N * log(N))` for `A` and `B` arrays as it stated in the question, say with some `O(F(N))` time complexity; so having an arbitrary `A` array we can *build* corresponding `B` with `O(N)` time complexity. Then combined complexity is

```
O(N) + O(F(N)) = O(F(N))
```

Since we have to loop over `B` array, `F(N)` can't be *better* than `O(N)` (and that's why we can drop `O(N)`: `O(N) + O(F(N)) = O(F(N))`). So far so good we've managed to sort *arbitrary* `A` array with time complexity

```
O(F(N)) < O(N * log(N))
```

We have *contradiction*, so the assumation that there's the algorithm is *wrong*.